# Can't save firebase upload image link

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

After searching for 2-3 days and trying different solutions, I do not know what the problem is. The picture is loaded and everything is fine, but in realtime it does not want to be saved in any way, I'm already confused where to form with getDownloadUrl, because both the call to ref and the call to task / uploadtask must return the correct value. I already even removed all the progress reader code in UploadImage and now there is code from firebase documentation.

- More specifically, here is the photo upload code:

```js
private void uploadImage() {
        StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + user.getUid());
        StorageReference fileRef = storage.child("ava" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(filePath);
        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "err1 = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "253 = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    newphotoUri = task.getResult();
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "uri = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "err2 = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Handle failures
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
       /* if (filePath != null) {
            UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(filePath);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //ошибка загрузки
                }
            });
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    //успешная загрузка

                    // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type,
                    // and download URL.
                    newphotoUri = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
                }
            });*/
        }
```

- and the code to save it:

```js
accept.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            uploadImage();
            String uid = user.getUid();
            String username = fN.getText().toString() + " " +
                    sN.getText().toString() + " " + lN.getText().toString();
            String pNumber = phone.getText().toString();
            String position = pos.getText().toString();
            String category = categ.getText().toString();
            String dateBirth = dBirth.getText().toString();
            String weight = wei.getText().toString();
            String growth = grow.getText().toString();
            String level = lvl.getText().toString();
            String preferredSport = prefS.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String photoUri = newphotoUri != null ? newphotoUri.toString() : null;
            Users newUser = new Users(uid, username, pNumber, position,
                    category, dateBirth, weight, growth, level, preferredSport, photoUri);
            isRef.child("Users").child("info").child(uid).setValue(newUser)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid ->
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "Профиль обновлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ProfileEdit.this.finish();
                        /*UserProfileChangeRequest changeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(firstName + secName)
                                .build();
                                user.updateProfile(changeRequest)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

                                        }).addOnFailureListener(e ->
                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "ERRORRESESE ." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());*/

                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e ->
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "ERROR/" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    });

        });


        bclose.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            this.finish();
        });
    }
```

- and the Users class by which the user data is written / read

```js
import android.net.Uri;

public class Users {


    public String uid, username, pNumber, position, category, dateBirth, weight, growth, level, preferredSport;
    public String photoUri;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String uid, String username, String pNumber, String position, String category,
                 String dateBirth, String weight, String growth, String level, String preferredSport, String photoUri) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
        this.pNumber = pNumber;
        this.position = position;
        this.category = category;
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.growth = growth;
        this.level = level;
        this.preferredSport = preferredSport;
        this.photoUri = photoUri;
    }
}
```

- well, all the ProfileEdit code if needed

```js
package 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.BuildConfig;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

import .Consts.Constant;
import .Consts.PhotoUri;
import .Consts.Users;
import .HomeNav;
import .R;
import .SignIn;

public class ProfileEdit extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText fN, sN, lN, pos, categ, lvl, dBirth, phone, wei, grow;
    private Button accept, bclose;
    private Spinner prefS;
    private final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private final FirebaseDatabase isDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private final DatabaseReference isRef = isDB.getReference();
    private final Calendar dateAndTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    private ImageView profileImg;
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private Uri filePath, newphotoUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_edit);
        setTitle("Редактировать");
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;   //null check
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) {
            finish();
        }
        GetAndSetUserInfo();
        init();
        dBirth.setOnKeyListener(null);
        dBirth.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                                if(hasFocus) {
                                                    setDate();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
        profileImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "PhotoUri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        accept.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            uploadImage();
            String uid = user.getUid();
            String username = fN.getText().toString() + " " +
                    sN.getText().toString() + " " + lN.getText().toString();
            String pNumber = phone.getText().toString();
            String position = pos.getText().toString();
            String category = categ.getText().toString();
            String dateBirth = dBirth.getText().toString();
            String weight = wei.getText().toString();
            String growth = grow.getText().toString();
            String level = lvl.getText().toString();
            String preferredSport = prefS.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String photoUri = newphotoUri != null ? newphotoUri.toString() : null;
            Users newUser = new Users(uid, username, pNumber, position,
                    category, dateBirth, weight, growth, level, preferredSport, photoUri);
            isRef.child("Users").child("info").child(uid).setValue(newUser)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid ->
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "Профиль обновлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ProfileEdit.this.finish();
                        /*UserProfileChangeRequest changeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(firstName + secName)
                                .build();
                                user.updateProfile(changeRequest)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

                                        }).addOnFailureListener(e ->
                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "ERRORRESESE ." + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());*/

                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e ->
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "ERROR/" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    });

        });


        bclose.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            this.finish();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), filePath);
                profileImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        bclose = findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        accept = findViewById(R.id.bAccept);
        fN = findViewById(R.id.eFName);
        sN = findViewById(R.id.eSName);
        lN = findViewById(R.id.eLName);
        pos = findViewById(R.id.ePos);
        categ = findViewById(R.id.eCategory);
        lvl = findViewById(R.id.eLvl);
        dBirth = findViewById(R.id.eDBirth);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.ePhoneN);
        wei = findViewById(R.id.eWeight);
        grow = findViewById(R.id.eGrowth);
        prefS = findViewById(R.id.sPrefSprt);
        profileImg = findViewById(R.id.profileImgEdit);
    }

    public void GetAndSetUserInfo() {
        isRef.child("Users").child("info").child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                if (users != null) {
                    fN.setText(users.username);
                    pos.setText(users.position);
                    categ.setText(users.category);
                    lvl.setText(users.level);
                    dBirth.setText(users.dateBirth);
                    phone.setText(users.pNumber);
                    wei.setText(users.weight);
                    grow.setText(users.growth);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void setDate() {
        new DatePickerDialog(ProfileEdit.this, d,
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                .show();
    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            setInitialDateTime();
        }
    };

    private void setInitialDateTime() {
        dBirth.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(ProfileEdit.this,
                dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR));
    }


    private void uploadImage() {
        StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + user.getUid());
        StorageReference fileRef = storage.child("ava" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(filePath);
        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "err1 = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "253 = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    newphotoUri = task.getResult();
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "uri = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "err2 = " + newphotoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Handle failures
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
       /* if (filePath != null) {
            UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(filePath);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //ошибка загрузки
                }
            });
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    //успешная загрузка

                    // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type,
                    // and download URL.
                    newphotoUri = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
                }
            });*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: The photoUrl is not replace with the new one because you straight out to save the info.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **450** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the tips.
decided as follows. I wanted to save the uri by clicking a button in the user's information, but this caused an error, since the user can not always put a picture, and sometimes the uri returns null because the file does not have time to load and the link is not formed in time. And then I remembered that loading a picture is called already at the click of a button and I just wrote down a link to a picture in the photo upload block. Well, in short, here, even tightened

```js
uploadTask.continueWithTask(...).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();                                 //isRef it`s FirebaseReference
                        isRef.child("Users").child(userID).child("photoAva").setValue("url", downloadUri.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Handle failures
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            });
```

omg, and it took me 3 days to figure it out ...